# Drawing column/rows in incomplete css3 grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using css-grid to generate a grid like display. But this display does not contain an element for every cell.

Is it possible to draw the outline of every lines/rows using CSS without adding the missing elements?

Example of grid:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15px 25px 35px;
    grid-template-rows: 30px 20px 10px;
    grid-gap: 5px 5px;
}
.cell1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
    background: green;
}
.cell2 {
    grid-area: 3 / 3 / span 1 / span 1;
    background : blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell1"></div>
    <div class="cell2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by **draw the outline**?

Comment: Just drawing the grid. Something like https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5511fc7ce4b0a3782aa9418b/t/552ef12ee4b0e9ead81ceefd/1429139759978/learning-the-grid-method.jpg

Comment: It can be done without the grid itself, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344125/4679160)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have to add the remaining cells but just dont add a class.
I think you need the DOM element to render css without sth like canvas.

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25px 25px 25px;
    grid-template-rows: 25px 25px 25px;
    grid-gap: 0;
}

.grid > * {
   border: 1px solid rgb(137,153,175);
}

.cell1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
    background: green;
}
.cell2 {
    grid-area: 3 / 3 / span 1 / span 1;
    background : blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell1"></div>
    <div class="cell2"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ye i know this is a solution, I wanted to see if I missed something and it was doable without doing that.

Comment: @Py. the other comment shows how to draw background for each, it seems to do the job

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you can use background linear gradients, without `css-grid`

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25px 25px 25px;
    grid-template-rows: 25px 25px 25px;
    grid-gap: 5px 5px;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,transparent 25px,#CCC 25px,#CCC 30px),repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg,transparent,transparent 25px,#CCC 25px,#CCC 30px);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
}
.cell1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
    background: green;
}
.cell2 {
    grid-area: 3 / 3 / span 1 / span 1;
    background : blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell1"></div>
    <div class="cell2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is, in my example the grid is preset. In my real usage, the grid does not contain a set number of column/rows and the column/rows can change in size. I edited the question to reflect that more accurately

Comment: @Py Then the width/height attributes will be dependent by the number f items in the grid. As long as you know the size of one item and the spacing in between, you can use the code.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know that in advance.

Comment: Sadly, I don't see other option otside the first answer. @Py