# How to add grid for angular-gridster?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

How to add dynamic coordinate grid for [angular-gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster)?

My example http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/24/

```
<div ng-app="someApp" ng-controller="someCtrl">
    <div gridster="gridsterOpts">
        <ul>
            <li class="" gridster-item="block" ng-repeat="block in sorted_blocks">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{{ block.title }}</div>
                    <div class="panel-content image-responsive" 
                         ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + block.image + ')'}"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('someApp', ['gridster']).controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.gridsterOpts = 
    {
        resizable: {
            enabled: true
        },
        columns: 4,
        rows: 16,
        minRows: 4,
        margins: [0,0],
        floating: false
    };
    $scope.sorted_blocks = [{
        id: 1,
        sizeX: 1,
        sizeY: 1,
        image: 'http://i.imgur.com/NI1Xm16.jpg',
        title: 'title1',
        row: 1,
        col: 2
    }, {
        id: 2,
        sizeX: 2,
        sizeY: 1,
        image: 'http://i.imgur.com/x6qmeUY.jpg',
        title: 'title2',
        row: 0,
        col: 0
    }];
});
```

Css:

```
.panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.panel .panel-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-responsive {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The width of gridster`s field are fixed - 4 columns, the height are dynamic, from 4 to 16 rows.
I need to add grid under blocks, like [this](http://d1v8u1ev1s9e4n.cloudfront.net/54e5236f5ccacf314d464817).

Answer (score 1):

I found this [codepen by Jason Delia](https://codepen.io/jasonadelia/pen/DnrAe), plugging it into your gridster works.

You'd have to change the background color of course, but it should do what you need:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #434343;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#434343, #282828);
}

#content {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,  transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent), 
                    linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent);
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: **See Also**:  [How to make a grid (like graph paper grid) with just css?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861765/1366033)