# How to style a table like a grid?

Tags: html, css

How can I build something like this with vanilla CSS and make it flexible so that it doesn't break if I add more or less columns / rows ?

[image: table]

This is what I have at the moment, but it doesn't seem right...

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
th:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 130px;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>column one</th><th>column two</th><th>column three</th></tr>
  <tr><td>row one</td><td>c</td><td>c</td><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row two</td><td>c</td><td>c</td><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for you to use the `flex-box`?

Comment: @Baro no, anything works

Comment: Then just use a background image in the cells.

Comment: @MrLister It can't be an image, by anything i meant it doesn't have to be flexbox can be older CSS

Comment: Have you heard of CSS Grid layout? :-) Though I guess if you want to infinitely add more rows/columns it may not be the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is what you are looking for: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8wpx58z/3/)

Thanks to this Stack Overflow user for a very good answer for the  [grid backgrund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709375/4031083)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709375/4031083 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .04) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .04) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(transparent 3px, #f2f2f2 3px, #f2f2f2 98px, transparent 98px), linear-gradient(-90deg, #aaa 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 3px, #f2f2f2 3px, #f2f2f2 98px, transparent 98px), linear-gradient(#aaa 1px, transparent 1px), #f2f2f2;
  background-size: 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 100px 100px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: transparent;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 120px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}

/* COLOR ROW/CELL */

td {
  background-color: #ff00ff30;
}

td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #00ffff30;
}

/* COLOR ROW/CELL */

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #ff000040;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #00ff0040;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="head">
    <th></th>
    <th>column one</th>
    <th>column two</th>
    <th>column three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row one</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row two</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```