# Repeat a background image with gaps between the repeating image

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a gap between repeating images?

I have a 1px heigh solid horizontal black line SVG. I want to use this as a repeating background image. But with gaps (of 1.5em) between the vertical repeat. To create a lined paper look. The horizontal repeat should repeat with no gaps (to create the lined paper look on all width of screens).

I've tried using a repeating linear gradient, but at smaller window sizes it displays very faintly – a problem with sub-pixel rendering.

```
h1,
h2 {
    font-size: clamp(6.4rem, 4vw, 8rem);
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(1.5em - 1px), rgb(0, 0, 0) calc(1.5em - 1px), rgb(0, 0, 0) 1.5em );
}
```

UPDATE
The work around I've done is:

```
h1,
h2 {
    font-size: clamp(6.4rem, 4vw, 8rem);
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-image: url("images/lines.svg");
    background-size: 1.5em 1.5em;
}
```

I've made the SVG a square image 120px x 120px (8rem/80px x 1.5). The horizontal line has a stroke of 1px and is a non-scaling-stroke, so it should remain 1px even when the image is displayed very small.

```
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 120 120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m0 119h120" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71212660/8620333

Comment: Any reason for needing an SVG? A linear-gradient, which is mostly transparent, would do the job.

Comment: I've tried linear gradient but run into trouble with sub-pixels on smaller devices. I'll update my question

Comment: Ah, yes, understood - but would an SVG suffer the same? Not sure.

Comment: It's possible in SVG files to set strokes not to scale, so I'm looking into using a SVG

Comment: Interesting solution. Is it working? You can answer your own question which could help future readers.

Comment: It seems to work, but I want to test it on my devices/browers before answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It appears to work.

```
h1,
h2 {
    font-size: clamp(6.4rem, 4vw, 8rem);
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-image: url("images/lines.svg");
    background-size: 100% 1.5em;
}
```

I've made the SVG a square image 120px x 120px (8rem/80px x 1.5). The horizontal line has a stroke of 1px and is a non-scaling-stroke, so it should remain 1px even when the image is displayed very small.

```
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 120 120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m0 119h120" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```