# How to make dashed line grid paper like background in CSS

Tags: css

How do I create dashed line grid paper like pattern in CSS?
My current code draws grid, but my line is not dashed.

```
background-size: 100px 100px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#f0f0f0 1px,transparent 1px),linear-gradient(to bottom,#f0f0f0 1px,transparent 1px);
background-position: top center;
```

I'd like to create background like this:
https://www.pixtastock.com/illustration/53928114

Comment: to do so, you have to make a bit more CSS, refer this example https://playcode.io/css

Comment: I couldn't preview the example :(

Comment: See here, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540194/how-to-make-a-grid-like-graph-paper-grid-with-just-css

Comment: Thank you, that code didn't work for me. It gives me solid lines.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76142563/20896315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use background-image with an [encoded SVG inside](https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/how-to-add-svgs-with-css-background-image/) a URL for this. The [SVG URL encoder](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) is pretty handy for this. You can develop an SVG then use the [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) to make it dashed. Example code below

```css
body {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-0 -0 10 10'%3E%3Cpath d='M 0 1 L 10 1 M 1 0 L 1 10' stroke='%23404040' stroke-dasharray='1' stroke-width='0.1' /%3E%3C/svg%3E"); 
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome Kayak

Comment: IF you could upvote and accept my answer that'd be appreciated. Ta.

Comment: @Adam I will upvote your answer it's very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, a CSS only solution without using a SVG.
Just tweak the CSS variables for your need and you are done.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0nt7v9bj/

```css
.dashed-grid-paper {

    --grid-size: 30px;
    --grid-strength: 1px;
    --grid-dash: 5px;
    --grid-gap: 10px;
    --grid-color: #ddd;
    --paper-color: #fff;

  background-color: var(--paper-color);
  background-size: var(--grid-gap) var(--grid-gap), var(--grid-size) var(--grid-size);
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent var(--grid-dash), var(--paper-color) var(--grid-dash)), 
    linear-gradient(to right, var(--grid-color) var(--grid-strength), transparent var(--grid-strength)),
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent var(--grid-dash), var(--paper-color) var(--grid-dash)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--grid-color) var(--grid-strength), transparent var(--grid-strength));
}
```

```html
<body class="dashed-grid-paper">
<p style="margin: 40px">How to make a dashed line grid paper<br>like background using CSS only.</p>
</body>
```