# CSS multiple repeating linear gradients not working

Tags: css

I am trying to create a visual effect like this (ignore black border due to screenshot):

[image]

I tried this style (also ignore backgroun color which can change):

```css
.bg {
    height: 100px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, #939393, #939393 1.25px, #9bceae 1.25px, #9bceae 6.25px ), 
            repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, #939393, #939393 1.25px, #9bceae 1.25px, #9bceae 6.25px );
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, #939393, #939393 1.25px, #9bceae 1.25px, #9bceae 6.25px ), 
            repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, #939393, #939393 1.25px, #9bceae 1.25px, #9bceae 6.25px );
```

Even in the [Try It](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient#try_it) section, it only renders the first gradient being applied. So lines appear only vertically in above style. Above style is what I have already tried, how can I render these checked strips design?

Comment: The second gradient is under the first one, if change `#9bceae` to `rgb(155, 206, 174, 0.5)`, you will find both gradient were rendered.

Comment: @Shuo This worked perfectly, feel free to provide this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: you can use one gradient for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71212660/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Try this and It'll work as expected. You can change the background color through the CSS property as mentioned in the code snippet.

```
.bg {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #9bceae !important; 
    background: 
        repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #939393, #939393 1.25px, transparent 1.25px, transparent 6.25px),
        repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #939393, #939393 1.25px, transparent 1.25px, transparent 6.25px);
}
```