# Transferring Large Data from Web Worker to Main Thread in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, web-worker, konvajs, konva, vue-konva

I am facing challenges in efficiently transferring a large dataset (potentially more than a million items) generated in a Web Worker to the main thread in my Vue.js application. Currently, when I try to pass the generated grid from the worker to the main thread, it leads to errors such as "maximum call stack size exceeded" or even crashes the page.

Here's a simplified version of my current Web Worker code:

```
// gridWorker.js
self.onmessage = function (e) {
  const { isUpdateColor, row, col, cellSize } = e.data;

  if (isUpdateColor) {
    const grid = Array.from({ length: row }, (_, i) => {
      return Array.from({ length: col }, (_, j) => {
        return {
          i,
          j,
          code: `spot_${i}_${j}`,
          // ... other properties
        };
      });
    });

    self.postMessage({ grid });
  }
};
```

```
//main thread
<v-stage>
    <v-layer ref="pathFinderLayer">
        <div v-if="showTravelDistancePage">
          <template v-for="rows in grid">
            <v-rect v-for="(item, index) in rows" :key="item.code + '-' + index" :config="item"
              @click="gridClick(item)" />
          </template>

        </div>
      </v-layer>
</v-stage>


methods:
prepareGrid(isUpdateColor,cleanPath=true) {
    this.gridWorker = new GridWorker();
      this.gridWorker.onmessage = (event) => {
        const { grid } = event.data;
          this.grid = grid;
        }

      };
}
```

I suspect the issue arises from trying to pass such a large dataset to the main thread. Is there a more efficient way to handle this situation? Even when I pass partial data chunk by chunk, its still crash my page if the grid object is too many.

Approach 1: Generating on Main Thread

Initially, I attempted to generate the large grid directly on the main thread. However, this approach led to page crashes due to the sheer volume of objects.

Approach 2: Generating in Web Worker and Passing Entire Grid

To address the performance issues, I moved the grid generation process to a Web Worker. While this successfully offloaded the generation to a separate thread, passing the entire generated grid back to the main thread still resulted in page crashes.

Approach 3: Generating in Web Worker Chunk by Chunk

In the latest attempt, I opted to generate the grid in chunks within the Web Worker. I then passed each chunk individually to the main thread, storing the chunks inside the main grid. Unfortunately, this strategy also led to crashes at a certain point.

Comment: The problem more likely comes from trying to render that many DOM elements at the same time. You even said yourself that when the data stayed in the main thread it still crashed. For visualizing huge datasets like that a DOM based approach is probably not the best. Usual solutions involve, pagination or scrolled based rendering (i.e. you don't render what's not on screen), or bitmap rendering using a <canvas> element.

Comment: But I need to show the grid to the user like this:-
1. https://ibb.co/phqRsCv
2. https://ibb.co/N7qqwFR
3. https://ibb.co/HDyVNrf

So it needs to be rendered on the main thread am I right? Is there a better way to do this without render it on the main thread like maybe generate image or something?

Comment: I'm not really into vue, but if I understand correctly, you're creating at least one element per cell of the grid, right? First, when you reach a million cells that means that each cell only gets a 1x1px on a 1000x1000px page. You can't even render the stroke. Then, you don't need to render each cell as its own element, you could render just the lines ([even just by CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540194)) and then through JS do the maths for which cell is being hovered by the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Seems XY problem. A short answer - you shouldn't do such things as generating a million items UI data.
You should only generate data visible on the screen, that's called called a virtual scrolling.
So you generate you data on the fly when needed.

If you still need to generate 1 million items ahead, do that in a worker and transfer only visible data on scrolling.

An example with a simple virtual list (it would even scroll much better). As you see I generate HTML on the fly (a more advanced scrolling would offset the top item imitating scrolling within an item too):

```js
const arr = Array.from({length:1000000}, () => Math.random());

unorderedList.style.height = (arr.length * 32) + 'px';

drawItems();

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', drawItems);

function drawItems(){
  const pos = wrapper.scrollTop;
  const from = pos / 32 | 0;
  const to = from + wrapper.offsetHeight / 32 | 0 + 1;
  unorderedList.innerHTML = arr.slice(from, to).map((item, idx) => `<li>${from + idx + 1}: ${item}</li>`).join('');
  let top = -32;
  [...unorderedList.children].forEach((li, idx) => li.style.top = `${top += 32}px`);
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li{
 position:absolute;
 height:32px;
 line-hieght:32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
</div>
```